# Backbone collection giving "Ajax of undefined" error when fetch() is called

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, backbone.js

I am just starting out with backbone and I am trying out a VERY basic script. I understand how things work but seem to be getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ajax' of undefined" when calling fetch on my collection. Code below:

JS :: localhost:8888/js/person.modal.js

```
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({    
defaults: {
    name: '',
    birthYear: ''
}
});
var PersonCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model : Person,
    url: 'names.json'    
});
var people = new PersonCollection();
people.fetch();
console.log(people.models) // if I comment out line above this = []
```

JSON :: localhost:8888/js/names.json

```
[
    { "name": "Linda", "birthYear": 1947},
    { "name": "Kat", "birthYear": 1977},
    { "name": "Jeff", "birthYear": 1989}
]
```

My code is running on a pretty simple node.js file server from my desktop. Only using Backbone.js and underscore.js. My JSON is being seen as application/json when I call it in the browser. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backbone's RESTful persistence features require jQuery. `fetch` calls `$.ajax`, and if jQuery isn't there, then `$` is undefined.